# original_order and Arrays in FlatBuffers

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

The documentation says about original_order:

"original_order (on a table): since elements in a table do not need to be stored in any particular order, they are often optimized for space by sorting them to size. This attribute stops that from happening."

I'm a bit confused now. I considered FlatBuffers tables to be similar to arrays in C++, and in my code I didn't see any issue. For example, I define a LineString geometry like this:

```
table Vec2List {
    p:[Vec2];
}

table Linestring {
    points:Vec2List;
}
```

That works. Though is it required to declare original_order?

Source: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__schemas.html

Comment: What does this question have to do with C++?

Comment: It's compiled into C++ code (structs and getter / setters), where above defined tables should be treated as arrays in the C++ struct defs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `original_order`. `original_order` affects the order of fields in a `table`. Your tables have only one field, so it would have no effect anyway. Vectors are never affected. I forgot why we even have that flag, there is no use for it under normal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I already guessed it had to do with alignment or something like that, but thought "elements in a table" are object instances of a struct and not fields it. But doesn't the field reordering lead to unexpected behavior, because the documentation also says that fields should be added at the end for new versions of a schema? Doesn't field reordering then cause problems when "readers" of a previous schema version try to access the struct?

Comment: the order of fields in a schema (or their ids) reflects upon the order of fields in a vtable in the binary representation. This order must indeed stay consistent. But the vtable then points to the actual fields, which can be serialized in the object in any order. (This is for tables.. structs don't have a vtable and can never be extended or reordered).